# Isolate image shadow with OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I have seen some algorithms on how to remove a shadow from an image using OpenCV with C++. I have looked around but haven't find the way to not just erase the shadow, but store it on a new image alone.
What I am doing with this code is to convert the original image (that I obtained from the Internet) to the HSV color space, change the value of V=180, which somehow removes the shadow, and then converting the image back to the BGR color space. I am clueless on how to 'extract' the removed shadow and save it to a different image...

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Mat srcImg;
    Mat hsvImg;
    Mat bgrImg;

    srcImg = imread("pcb-2008.jpg");
    cvtColor(srcImg, hsvImg, CV_BGR2HSV);
    imwrite("1.hsv.jpg", hsvImg);

    Mat channel[3];
    split(hsvImg, channel);
    channel[2] = Mat(hsvImg.rows, hsvImg.cols, CV_8UC1, 180);
    merge(channel, 3, hsvImg);
    imwrite("2.hsvNoShadow.jpg", hsvImg);

    cvtColor(hsvImg, bgrImg, CV_HSV2BGR);
    imwrite("3.backToBgr.jpg", bgrImg);

    return 0;
 }
```

[Sample image of a PCB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ4Qi.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the problem you ran into? Share your code.

Comment: Hi ! Welcome to Stack Overflow. Kindly have a look at [How do i ask a good question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: removing thank you comments

Comment: I have added more details to the question, the sample code and an image...

Comment: @Mittal, please check the code I shared, would this be possible with OpenCV?